# Guidance with jQuery counter

Tags: jquery

I need a counter function that counts up or down to a target value. I'd like to know if there's an easy to use plugin available or if I can create the function myself, but I would need guidance as where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are lot of counter plugins available. You can use the [**jQuery roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin as the counter with your custom logic.

Based on your previous question you already used the roundSlider plugin, so that I suggested the same to achieve your current requirement also.

### [**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/u1p6qLgL/)

Here instead of month and days you can use any numbers also.

[image: roundslider as number / days counter]